# Align text and image to right on this CSS

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm running a little issue here and can't find a solution so I ask here for some help. I'm building a [website](http://comvivem.treswd.com/net/) and I use [Foundation Zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/) as base layout. Well at page header if yours login as demo/demo123 you'll see a avatar image and beside some links to go to profile, logout and User Name. I need to fix this code by align those text to right but before the image. Maybe my markup is ugly so I accept suggestions on  this topic. You can try with several users for testing purpose:

```
demo/demo123, 1632dd55e/1qazxsw2, 1632e8322/1qazxsw2
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Try to improve your question's title. "This CSS" gives nothing valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think generally what's wrong is you're mis-using the grid system by trying to have 12 columns inside 8 columns, a list where it makes no sense to have a list, and other issues. It was easiest for me to rewrite the user panel section of your markup, and then style it without having to worry so much about overriding things.

I would replace the div currently classed "eight columns mobile-three" with the following:

```
<div class="eight columns mobile-three user-panel">
  <div class="user-controls">
    <ul>
      <li class="account-options"><a href="http://comvivem.treswd.com/net/my-profile">Opciones de cuenta</a></li>
      <li class="logout-link"><a href="http://comvivem.treswd.com/net/users/logout">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="user">
    <span class="user-name">Demo</span>
    <a class="avatar" href="http://comvivem.treswd.com/net/users/view/2">
      <img title="Demo&nbsp;Demo" alt="Demo&nbsp;Demo" style="" src="uploads/default/files/kung_fu_panda.gif">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then remove all existing styles on `.user-panel` and its descendant elements.  Add the following styling:

```
.user-panel {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: right;
}

.user-panel a { color: #FFFFFF; }
.user-panel .user-controls {
    margin: 9px 54px 0 0;
}
.user-panel .user-controls ul { list-style-type: none; }
.user-panel .user-controls li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.user-panel .user-controls li:not(:last-child):after {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    content: "|";
    padding: 0 3px 0 6px;
}

.user-panel .user {
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 0;
}
.user-panel .user .user-name {
    bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 54px;
    position: relative;
}
.user-panel .user .avatar {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 8px;
    width: 54px;
}
.user-panel .user .avatar img {
    max-height: 54px;
    max-width: 54px;
}
```

That should produce a layout like [this](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/654/9560872079.png), which I'm assuming is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but didn't works don't know the cause because make changes as you suggested. This is how looks like using your suggestions: http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/654/1537322759.png and this is what I need to get http://easycaptures.com/2013929056

Comment: Because you did not put in the markup I gave you, you've put in something different. Also you left the style for `.account-options, .logout-link`, which should be removed.  I've updated the CSS in my answer to match your screenshot.

Comment: I check all over again and fix the problems but still not working

Comment: You have classed the controls div as `users-controls` rather than `user-controls`. Your avatar anchor element is missing the class `avatar`. Other than that, `.avatar` needs `top: 8px` or so, which I've added to my answer.

Comment: Nice it's working now but still a little problem and is with Logout (Salir) link because if you pass the mouse pointer over the latest strings don't works meaning I think div class="user" is overlaping or don't know. I tried setting z-index: 1 for div class="user" and z-index:10 for div class="user-controls" but didn't work still the same behaviour so I need your help a bit more, anyway I accept the answer and give you de points because you help me a lot

Comment: If you want to set z-index on something you must give it a `position` of relative, absolute, or fixed.  `position: relative; z-index: 10;` on `.user-panel .user-controls li` will work for you I believe. You can also simply switch the order of the user-controls and user divs without any further CSS changes.

Comment: niceeeee man you rocks and help me a lot. All is working perfect by now

Comment: Hi, man I'm having some issues at Chrome, all works fine in Firefox (didn't try in IE9) but in Chrome the span.user-name is moved to the right and appears behind the image, I was trying to found where it fails but can't. Could you please give me a little help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change theese lines to float values instead. So they are fluid to each other and not lies on topo of each other.

line 98
.avatar{position: absolute; right: 0;}

line 100
.user-name {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    right: 0;

}